# Rails 4 - link_to with confirm in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

I'm trying to customize my dialog confirm the link_to in rails 4. But I do not understand why he rides the html as "confirm", and should be "data-confirm"!

I've tried a number of ways, and it is always generated "confirm", like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', user, :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>

<a confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/user/13">Delete</a>
```

I followed this tutorial:
http://thelazylog.com/custom-dialog-for-data-confirm-in-rails/
and i used the example in tutorial, but also doesn't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Confirm has been deprecated in rails 4.

So use new syntax:

```
<%= link_to "title", "#", data: {confirm: "Are you sure!"} %>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the same behavior in rails 7 you should use `turbo_confirm` key instead:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', user,
  data: {turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```